Statistical model / test for difference in change over time for two conditions
I have data from an experiment that looks like this:



rep 1 T=0
rep 2 T=0
rep 1 treatment
rep 2 treatment
rep 1 control
rep 2 control




0
3
3
7
2
4


1
4
3
8
1
4


...
...
...
...
...
...



The statistical question I'm trying to answer is whether all observations (all rows) differed in their change after T=0 in the treatment group versus the control group (whether observations as a whole significantly differed in their response to treatment compared to control).
What is the most appropriate statistical approach to test this hypothesis using all available data? I believe it is a mixed effects model but am not quite sure how to set it up.
Edit: Note that data are "paired" - each row represents two replicates, each an independent unit that is split in half and each half independently exposed to both treatment and control. Each row is a biological replicate and each "replicate" column is a technical replicate thereof.

The first point is about the pairing. It depends on how exactly the independent units are "split in half", and what exactly the variable you measure is. Are the 2 halves of Rep1 really identical, at least from the perspective of the variable being measured? And are these 2 halves identical (again wrt the measured variable) to the whole unit? Since there are no details about it, we can not really assess. Therefore, I will take assume that they indeed are, as the OP describes.
In this case, you can then re-arrange your data. You currently have a 6xN table (where $N$ is the total number of "pairs"; re-arrange it as a 3x$2N$ table such as
|   T=0   | treatment | control |
| ------- | --------- | ------- |
| 0    | 3    | 2    |
| 3    | 7    | 4    |
| 1   | 3    | 1    |
| 4   | 8    | 4    |
| ...   | ...   | ...    |
Then compute the differences $Treatment-T_0$ and $Control-T_0$ and run paired tests (e.g. paired t-test, for comparing means, or paired Sign test for comparing medians, etc.).
Note that the paired tests are executed on a variable which simplifies to just $Treatment - Control$, so the measurements at $T_0$ are not used... So you can directly jump to that difference, and run 1-sample tests on it...
But if you had not split the units in half (so, no pairing), you would have needed the $T_0$ measurement, to adjust for any initial difference between treatment and control group. And you would have to use 2-sample tests, which have lower power...
